# Function not implemented: 'lib' -> 'my/path/to/venv/lib64'

Tags: python, virtualenv, environment, lib, manjaro

OS: Manjaro
Python: 3.8

On my computer I have 2 partitions, one is where my Manjaro is installed, and the other one it's a secondary SSD.
Every time when I'm running this command `virtualenv env` into my secondary SSD I'm getting the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/usr/bin/python3' ->
'path/to/my/env/bin/python'
```

Also the same with this command `python3 -m venv tutorial-env` I'm getting the same error.

But the interesting fact is that if I'm trying to run any of those commands under my main partition everything works perfectly fine with no errors at all.

Could any of you help me to understand what's going on here and why the heck I'm getting this error? Also, how can I fix it? Because I really need to create a python environment under that secondary partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SSD is most probably formatted as FAT filesystem, FAT doesn't implement symlinks and virtualenvs by default use symlinks to that version of python they have been created with. You can try `virtualenv --always-copy` to avoid symlinks on the second disk.

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks to you so much for your help :D. Just one more thing because I'm not sure... what are symlinks and why do I need it in the first place?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link; https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsymlink%5D+what+is; `virtualenv` uses symlinks to avoid copying files; this makes creating of a virtual env faster and takes less disk space. Unfortunately sometimes — when symlinks don't work — `virtualenv` must be directed to use copy.